# Deedle - what's the schema format for readCsv

Tags: f#, deedle

I was using Deedle in F# to read a txt file (no header) to data frame, and cannot find any example about how to specify the schema.

```
let df= Frame.ReadCsv(datafile, separators="\t", hasHeaders=false, schema=schema)
```

I tried to give a string with names separated by ',', but seems don't work.

```
let schema = @"name, age, address";
```

I did some search on the doc, but only find following - don't know where I can find the info. :(

> [schema - A string that specifies CSV schema. See the documentation
>   for information about the schema format.](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-frame.html)

Answer (score 2):

The schema format is the same as in [the CSV type provider in F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html).

The only problem (quite important!) is that the Deedle library had a bug where it completely ignores the `schema` parameter, so no matter what you provide, it would be ignored.

I just submitted a pull request that fixes the bug and also includes some examples (in the form of unit tests). See the [pull request here](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/pull/104) (and click on "Files changed" to see the samples).

If you do not want to wait for a new release, just get the code from my GitHub fork and build it using `build.cmd` in the root (run this for the first time to restore packages). The complete build requires local installation of R (because it builds R plugin too), but it should build `Deedle.dll` and then fail... (After the first run of `build.cmd`, you can just use `Deedle.sln` solution).