# Deedle - how to use 'ParseExact' within the Frame.ReadCsv schema

Tags: csv, parsing, f#, schema, deedle

I have a CSV file of data in the form

21.06.2016 23:00:00.349, 153.461, 153.427

21.06.2016 23:00:00.400, 153.460, 153.423

etc

The initial step of creating a frame involves the optional inclusion of a 'schema' to specify or rename column heads and specify types:

```
let df = Frame.ReadCsv(__SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/data/GBPJPY.csv", hasHeaders=true, inferTypes=false, schema="TS (DateTimeOffset), Bid (float(3)), Ask (float(3))")
```

I would like to specify the first column of string values to be ParseExact'ed to DateTimeOffset of the format

"dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"

(I'm assuming the use of the setting System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

How do I express the schema such that it will parse the datetime string in that first Frame.ReadCsv("file.csv", schema = ........ )? Or is this not possible to accomplish within the schema statement?

Comment: I realize I can do this as a secondary step once the data is loaded, but I'm not sure if I'm understanding the 'schema' options correctly - I see that it uses the format of the CSVProvider, and have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674975/deedle-whats-the-schema-format-for-readcsv?rq=1  but I don't see anyway to use a DateTimeOffset.ParseExact method....or does the Frame.ReadCsv process automatically figure out the DateTime format of the first column string?

Comment: I will probly in the meantime just use a seq{ textreader...split...ParseExact()} and bring it in that way and use the Deedle conversion option to turn a collection into a frame....since the 'schema' info is a bit sparse.

Comment: OK, I'm seeing the use of                               
     (frame).IndexRows<DateTime>("Column Name").SortRowsByKey();

Comment: And this blog, https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/a-primer-on-manipulating-data-frame.html , uses a step                                                  
|> Seq.map (fun (date, title, amount) -> { Date = string date |> DateTime.Parse to parse the datetime data after loading it....